# Trying to pass an array of pointers to objects, to a function of another class in C++ (not allowed to use vectors)

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, pass-by-reference

I have a class named Student. I create many student objects in my main (each object representing one student.)What i'm really trying to do is pass each one of these students to function enter of School class, representing that a student enters the school and then print his/her name etc.Here's the code:

my study.h file consists of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
  
  class Student
    {
    private:
        string name;
        int no_floor;
        int no_classroom;
    public:
        Student(const string& nam,int no_fl,int no_cla)//constructor
        : name(nam), no_floor(no_fl), no_classroom(no_cla)
        {
          cout << "A new student has been created! with name " << name << " heading to floor: "<< no_floor << " class: " << no_classroom << endl;
        };
        ~Student() //destructor
       {
           cout << "A Student to be destroyed! with name " << name << " is at floor: " << no_floor << " class: " << no_classroom;
       };
```

Then the School class:

```
class School
       {
       private:
             Student* pointer_array[2];
       public:
             School()//constructor
             {
               cout << "A New School has been created!" << endl;
             };
             ~School(){//destructor
               cout << "A School to be destroyed!" << endl;
             };
             void enter(Student student, int stc=0/*student counter*/);
       };
```

on my main.cpp file: (memory allocation for each student)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <study.h>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
      //Student creation
   int i,floor,classroom;
   string stname;
   Student* students[2];
   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
      cin >> stname;
      cin >> floor;
      cin >> classroom;
      students[i] = new Student(stname, floor, classroom);
   }



   School sch;
   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
      sch.enter(*(students[i]),i);
   }

   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
     delete students[i];
   }
}
```

Lastly on my study.cpp file i've got the School class function where i'm trying to pass each object **by reference and not by coping them to a new object**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <study.h>

using namespace std;

void School::enter(Student student, int stc/*student counter*/)
{
  pointer_array[stc] = &student;
  cout << "pointer array[" << stc <<  "]:" << pointer_array[stc] << endl; 
  //^ this cout prints the same adress for both students array[0]:0x1ffefffd20
  //                                                     array[1]:0x1ffefffd20

}
```

Any ideas on how to pass pointers to all students and not just one. Again i'm trying to pass the array by reference.Thoughts?

Comment: May I ask why you're using pointers, and arrays? Do you happen to know what `std::vector` is?

Comment: `pointer_array[stc] = &student;` stores a pointer to a local copy of `Student` - it's not too surprising it always has the same address, considering you are calling the function in a loop

Comment: @cigien in the project i'm doing i'm not allowed to use any other libraries except cstring

Comment: @UnholySheep hey thanks for the notice! Do you happen to know what to do to fix it?

Comment: Ah, I suspected as much. You have my sympathies :( You should ask your teacher why they've imposed this constraint. And in the meantime, if you really want to learn C++, check out `vector`.

Comment: @cigien ahaha i appreciate the sympathy :)

Comment: The problem in the shown code is a well known problem called "useless use of pointers". Nothing in the shown code requires the use of `new`, or `delete`. Using `new` to create a pointer to a new object, but then immediately making a useless copy of the same object in order to pass it by value to another function -- this doesn't really accomplish anything useful.

Comment: The quick fix would be to change the function parameter to take a pointer directly (`Student* student`) since you already have those `Student` objects dynamically allocated anyway

Comment: @UnholySheep just tried it and the code doesn't compile. I will keep the advice in mind though. Thank you!

Comment: @ScatterBrainer the code won't compile by changing _just_ the parameter because you will now need to also pass a pointer to the function, which you dereference when you call `*(students[i])`. You will need to change that to `students[i]`

Comment: @Human-Compiler you're actually right i just tried it and it worked guys thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the solution to this problem
School class:

```
class School
{
private:
      Student* pointer_array[5];
public:
      School()//constructor
      {
        cout << "A New School has been created!" << endl;
      };
      ~School(){//destructor
        cout << "A School to be destroyed!" << endl;
      };
      void enter(Student* student, int stc=0/*student counter*/);
};
```

Student class doesn't change:

```
class Student
    {
    private:
        string name;
        int no_floor;
        int no_classroom;
    public:
        Student(const string& nam,int no_fl,int no_cla)//constructor
        : name(nam), no_floor(no_fl), no_classroom(no_cla)
        {
          cout << "A new student has been created! with name " << name << " heading to floor: "<< no_floor << " class: " << no_classroom << endl;
        };
        ~Student() //destructor
       {
           cout << "A Student to be destroyed! with name " << name << " is at floor: " << no_floor << " class: " << no_classroom;
       };
```

Then main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <study.h>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
      //Student creation
   int i,floor,classroom;
   string stname;
   Student* students[2];
   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
      cin >> stname;
      cin >> floor;
      cin >> classroom;
      students[i] = new Student(stname, floor, classroom);
   }



   School sch;
   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
      sch.enter(students[i],i);
   }

   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
     delete students[i];
   }
}
```

Lastly the study.cpp function:

```
void School::enter(Student* student, int stc/*student counter*/)
{
  pointer_array[stc] = student;
  (pointer_array[stc])->print();
  cout << " enters school!" << endl;
  cout << "pointer array[" << stc <<  "]:" << pointer_array[stc] << endl;
}
```